# set up vpn with toonel

Tags: windows-7, vpn, proxy

I use [toonel](http://www.toonel.net) as proxy server to bypass filtering.
how can I set up a vpn connection on 127.0.0.1:8080 and use it?
I'm using windows 7 professional .

Comment: I just want to pass all my network traffic through this http proxy. not just my browser traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar file from [here](http://toonel.net/download.html#generic). Run toonel type typing `java -jar <toonel-file-name>`. 
Follow [these steps](http://toonel.net/webwin.html) to configure your browsers.

Comment: please read carefully before answering!

Comment: Which other network traffic ? Configure the relevant software to use a proxy with the above details. toonel is a proxy server, not a VPN endpoint

Comment: all my system network traffic. some software doesn't have options to change their proxy settings